What might cause these striations in this solder joint?
This is a 47 µF 1210 ceramic capacitor which failed. There is excessive leakage current through it and in the process of investigating, I found this unusual-looking solder joint:


We use a no-clean flux solder paste in our SMT reflow process. No other joints on the board had this appearance. It is also worth noting that the top of the terminal on this capacitor had what appears to be some sort of crack or void:

Are these defects most likely due to a contaminant, temperature problem, or something else?

At a guess, it might be flux-related, e.g., an excessively large glob that caused voids. Perhaps the applicator tip accumulated a glob that fell off there.

Fascinating failure. My guess is the Cap failure is from thermal shock and if there is a triboelectric charge from a forced air oven , it could charge up the solder and start repelling like rain and snowflakes but with striations from thermal gradients .  weird.

Could be an isolated defective crystaline flaw in the cap.

Does the equal spacing of striations indicate a force field separating the solder like a liquid plasma? The solder starts with particles of metal & flux but are there lines of force field repelling each other within the solder flux as they travel from hot to cold.

Dunno. Pattern just looks like grain growth from a low-alloy melt. Perhaps directional solidification occurred due to growth seeding from the pads (Cu/CnSn is probably adequate seeding, i.e. not implying partial melting; that said, was this HASL or--?), and slow cooling through the melt range. Are you sure no other similarly tall/bulky components have such a growth pattern?

I wonder if it violently (for the size) cracked under the thermal stress of soldering and that movement affected the joint appearance. The leakage is a typical side effect of cracking.

Looks to me like the surface of the solder formed a skin that wrinkled when the underlying melt contracted as it solidified. I don't remember this being any kind of defect under IPC-A-610 inspection criteria but I'll look again.

@TimWilliams PCB finish is ENIG

Those look nearly identical to the example photos of "cooling lines" in the IPC-A-610 standard (Acceptability of Electronic Assemblies). The standard does not explain why cooling lines occur, but states that lead-free solders are more likely to exhibit this condition [possibly due to lead-free solder's higher surface tension?]. Cooling lines are not a "disturbed solder" condition and are acceptable in all three classes of electronic assemblies.

I've just reviewed IPC-A-610 [5.2.9] and I am not seeing the same kind of parallel lines in the images for cooling lines nor secondary reflow. I can say to some extent that the secondary reflow images are slightly more similar, but not as pronounced. Under disturbed solder [5.2.8], I am thinking that is perhaps more similar. I'm unsure how to differentiate these phenomenon; the former is acceptable while the latter is considered a defect. I think I will pursue some input from our solder paste supplier as well as a failure analysis lab.

I can see on the top picture a suspicious looking line on the top surface down the length of the capacitor approximately midway between the two sides.
The outer surface of the capacitor is also dirty with what appears to be residue from being delivered in bulk packaging rather than tape and reel.
Were these placed direct from bulk or re-taped? Is the aspect ratio of the capacitors truly square? i.e. is the height of the capacitor consistent depending on the rotation around the long axis.
It looks suspiciously like a too-high placement force causing cracking originating on the top surface. I'd be asking your assembly vendor about the set height and placement force of the placement machine, and whether this could be wrong for bulk or re-taped components without a defined axial rotation because of that.

These caps should absolutely be tape and reel (not bulk), but you bring up some good questions. We have had issues with Z-height placement of these 1210 caps, which has resulted in failures, but never in (at least not by me) visible cracking. This one is the first, and also had this weird solder joint.

It looks like the vertical striations you're calling out are bridging a gap/void or some sort of contamination on the capacitor terminal (the dark area).
In this picture I've outlined what I think the body/terminal of the capacitor would normally look like with a red line.

The more I look, the more I think there's a chunk missing out of that end. I'd be curious to see if that was the case by desoldering the capacitor and trying to examine it directly under the microscope. Capacitor damage lines up with some of the other answers and comments calling out the marks on the top surface of that terminal.
IMO, damage to the capacitor would be a reasonable explanation for the original problem (excessive leakage current).

Interesting take. I have left the assembly alone for now, pending possible further analysis by a lab. I will report back if we find anything!

Not sure if this is relevant, but the thermal gradient of cooling can affect the tin dendrites in no-Pb solder.
The striations could be called parallel dendrites in the joint.  But I'm not sure how a longitudinal crack in the ceramic is an isolated defect that caused this or an effect from the cooling rate during liquidus.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226846745_Solidification_shrinkage_defects_in_electronic_solders

Quite interesting as well. I'm also unsure if this is related, but will report back if I am able to find more conclusive information from analysis and research.

There's some similarity (aside from the orientation of the lines) to the 'disturbed flux' photo in IPC-TM-650. Relevant since your boards will have no-clean
flux present.

Presumably a capacitor fracturing due to thermal stress, differential thermal coefficient, trapped moisture in a small pre-existing defect etc. could have a similar effect to solder or laminate fractures.
